# Choosing where the output of wxplot2d will be saved

Tags: maxima

I'm using wxplot2d with different gnuplot terminals and I'd like the files to be output to some directory other than what is set in the environment variable `maxima_tempdir`. Is it possible? Alternatively, can I, say, change the value of this variable during a wxMaxima session?

For an [example](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/maxima-gnuplot.html), I want `sin.eps` to be saved somewhere I choose during the session:

```
plot2d(sin(x),[x,0,2*%pi],[gnuplot_term,ps],[gnuplot_out_file,"sin.eps"]);
```

I'm using wxMaxima 16.04.2 on Windows 10 (1709).

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

Apparently, setting

```
maxima_tempdir:".";
```

will make the current directory, if wxMaxima was started from a `.wxm` file, the temp directory. This seems good enough for my purposes. I'll leave this open to see what others have to say.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution:

```
f(x) := sin(x)$
g(x) := cos(x)$

plot2d([f(x), g(x)], 
[x,-5,5],
[legend,"sin(x)","cos(x)"],
[xlabel,"x"],[ylabel,"y"],
[pdf_file,"./trigplot.pdf"],
[gnuplot_preamble,"set key box spacing 1.3 top right"])$
```

Note the value of `pdf_file` is set to `./trigplot.pdf`. Same goes for other outputs like "ps" or "svg". The plot is then saved to the current working directory.

The `maxima_tempdir` on linux in the above example is still set to `/tmp`.

Answer (score 0):

First save your directory to the variable :

```
path:"~/maxima/batch/my_dir/"$
```

Note:

- If path is an empty then file will be in your home dir
- path should end with "/"
- I do it manually with pwd bash command

Then change name of output file:

```
gnuplot_out_file : sconcat(path,"your_file_name")$
```

Your output file will be in desired directory now.

Example is [here](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Parabolic_orbits_insidse_upper_main_chessboard_box_for_f(z)_%3D_z%5E2_%2B0.25.svg)